# Как вставить форматированный текст в QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, c++

Никак не получается вставить форматированный текст из буфер-обмена в поле 'QTextEdit'. Текст появляется как обычный. Хочу вставлять тексты, где присутствует подсветка синтаксиса языка программирования. Например копировать коды с сайта `hashcode.ru` или `stackoverflow.com`.

Но вот что я заметил - если вставить текст-код скопированного из самого `Qt Creator`, то он четко появляется с подсветкой синтаксиса и соответствующими отступами.

[image]

Не понимаю, почему так происходит? Ведь текст с сайта и с `Qt Creator` предварительно копируется в буфер, а на выходе разный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, похоже, не у вас: при копировании текста с данных сайтов, скорее всего, отрабатывает какой-то хук, в результате чего метаинформация о форматировании сбрасывается (да как минимум достаточно определить, что это text/plain). Косвенно это подтверждается тем, что взяв Word 2007 и LibreOffice Writer 5 наблюдается ровно такая же картина (при копировании с ru.SO). А вот если взять какое-то другое форматирование, с тех же сайтов, но не привязанное к коду, то всё отлично сохраняется. Ну и стоит запастись какой-нибудь [тулзой](http://lifehacker.com/5298615/five-best-clipboard-managers), которая показывает, что у вас в буфере обмена и проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего разное форматирование текста (html-css)